# How do I specify which table row when entering golf score and associated calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which populates from a database the details about the selected golf course. In this table i have 18 rows, one for each hole. Each row populates data which resembles a golf scorecard and has an input for the score achieved on each hole.

I've figured out the code to calculate score and display on the first row, but how do I then do this for the other 17 holes

Table Code

```
echo "<tr>
        <td style='display:none;'><input type='number' class='form-control' name='holeID' id='hole".$row["holeID"]."' value=".$row["holeID"]." readonly tabindex='-1'></td>

        <td ><input type='number' class='form-control' name='holeNumber[]' id='hole".$row["holeNumber"]."' value=".$row["holeNumber"]." readonly tabindex='-1'></td>

        <td ><input type='number' class='text-center form-control' name='holePar[]' id='par".$row["holeNumber"]."' value=".$row["par"]." readonly tabindex='-1'></td>

        <td ><input type='number' class='text-center form-control strokeIndex' name='holeStrokeIndex[]' id='hole".$row["holeNumber"]."strokeIndex' value=".$row["strokeIndex"]." readonly tabindex='-1'></td>

        <td ><input type='number' class='text-center form-control strokesReceived' name='strokesReceived' id='hole".$row["holeNumber"]."strokesReceived' value='' readonly tabindex='-1'></td>

        <td ><select class='form-control scoreInput' id='scoreInputHole".$row["holeNumber"]."' name='scoreInput' >
    <option value='' disabled selected hidden>Input Score..</option>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
    <option value='7'>7</option>
    <option value='8'>8</option>
    <option value='9'>9</option>
    <option value='NR'>NR</option>  
</td>

        <td ><input type='number' class='text-center form-control pointsScored' name='pointsScored' id='hole".$row["holeNumber"]."points' value='' readonly tabindex='-1'></td>

        </tr>";
```

Code for score calc

```
 $(document).on('change','#scoreInput',function(){
        alert($('#scoreInput :selected').val()+ " shots");

        var score = $('#scoreInput :selected').val();

        var par = document.getElementById('par1').value;

        var pointsScored = document.getElementsByName('pointsScored');

        alert ("Par " + par);

        var strokesReceived = document.getElementById('hole1strokesReceived').value;

    alert (strokesReceived + " strokes received");

    points = (parseFloat(par) + parseFloat(strokesReceived)) - parseFloat(score) + parseFloat(2);

    if(points < 1 || score == "NR"){
                    points = 0
                }

            alert (points + " points");

                pointsScored[0].setAttribute('value',points);

            });
```

Ok, i have changed code to below and each line is working as expected, referencing the correct values, I'm now having an issue getting the pointsScored to show , error is

Uncaught TypeError: pointsScored.setAttribute is not a function

or

adminEventScoreEntry.php?id=1:837 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).find(...).setAttribute is not a function

```
 $(document).on('change','.scoreInput',function(){

                var score = $(this).children('option:selected').val();

                var par = $(this).closest('tr').find('.par').val();

                var pointsScored = $(this).closest('tr').find('.pointsScored');

                var strokesReceived = $(this).closest('tr').find('.strokesReceived').val();

                var points = (parseFloat(par) + parseFloat(strokesReceived)) - parseFloat(score) + parseFloat(2);

                console.log ("Score is "+score);
                console.log ("Par is "+par);
                console.log (strokesReceived + " strokes received");


                if(points < 1 || score == "NR"){
                    points = 0

                console.log (points +" points scored");

                $(this).closest('tr').find('.pointsScored').setAttribute('value', points);


                } else {

                    console.log (points +" points scored");
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.pointsScored').setAttribute('value', points);
                }

            });
        });
```

Comment: You can't repeat element ID's in  page. They are unique by definition

Comment: which are repeated?
id='hole".$row["holeID"]."'
id='hole".$row["holeNumber"]."'
id='par".$row["holeNumber"]."'
id='hole".$row["holeNumber"]."strokeIndex'
id='hole".$row["holeNumber"]."strokesReceived'
id='hole".$row["holeNumber"]."points'

Comment: `id='scoreInput'` ....

Comment: missed that! Thanks

Comment: have edited code above to give unique ID

Comment: ok but now you have to modify your jQuery to account for it. Use class to target the `<select>` . It's current value is `$(this).val()`. It's parent row is `$(this).closest('tr')` from which you can find other elements in same row using their common class name

Comment: @charlietfl sorted, updated code in answer, thanks for the subtle hint!

Comment: Great!...remember this pattern. Is extremely common with repeating parts of a page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out,

```
  $(document).on('change','.scoreInput',function(){

                var score = $(this).children('option:selected').val();

                var par = $(this).closest('tr').find('.par').val();

                var pointsScored = $(this).closest('tr').find('.pointsScored');

                var strokesReceived = $(this).closest('tr').find('.strokesReceived').val();

                var points = (parseFloat(par) + parseFloat(strokesReceived)) - parseFloat(score) + parseFloat(2);

                console.log ("Score is "+score);
                console.log ("Par is "+par);
                console.log (strokesReceived + " strokes received");


                if(points < 1 || score == "NR"){
                    points = 0

                console.log (points +" points scored");

                $(this).closest('tr').find('.pointsScored').attr('value', points);


                } else {

                    console.log (points +" points scored");
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.pointsScored').attr('value', points);
                }

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"How do I specify which table row when entering golf score and associated calculation?"*

jQuery provides so many ways to accomplish one's objective that the real trick is how far back are you willing to go back and refactor your code. I find myself starting all over with a completely new approach -- which is what I did to the OP's code.

Here's a brief outline:

- The htmlString that is rendered for each table row has changed:

  - Template Literal is used instead of the cumbersome and antiquated String Literal.
  - The first column is removed -- looked useless and besides that it was `display: none` with no apparent intentions to use it in the future.
  - All ids were simplified for my sanity. All names and ids were formatted to a readable client-side HTML/CSS/JavaScript standards. Feel free to redo any naming conventions -- keeping in mind all references to and from said names, ids, classes, etc.
- If you are going to use more than one form control then you should take advantage of the `<form>` tag as well. `form#scoreCard` is wrapped around the `<table>` and is registered to the input event.
- The first function `addRow()` passes three parameters: 1. `table` [String] selector of a table or tbody. 2. `idx` [Integer] an externally declared counter and 3. `row` [Integer] the number of rows to append to a table.
- The second function is `calcScore()` which is triggered on any input event occurring on `form#scoreCard`. It delegates the input event rather than the change event. An `.each()` method on this selector/chained methods:

> ```
> $('tr').find(':input, output').each(function() {...
> ```

What this is doing is approaching the targeted form controls from above instead of from below. It will collect all `<tr>` and then funnel it's way down to all form controls on *each `<tr>`*. So by going from a broad range: *All `<tr>s`* then to a narrow specified target: `.find()` forces a linear search on each `<tr>` one after another. So on each in one pass every form control is accessed one after the other on every row. No dependencies on ids nor are there any indexes to track. By referencing classes and having tight control of the flow with if/else statements, all 18 rows will instantly calculate the scores when the user enters data in `.par`, `.score`, or `.strokes` `<input>s`.

```js
var idx = 0;

function addRow(table, idx, rows) {
  while (idx < rows) {
    ++idx;
    $(table).append(
      `<tr>
   <td>
     <output id='hole${idx}' class='form-control hole' name='hole' tabindex='-1'>${idx}</output>
   </td>
  <td>
  <select class='custom-select par text-center' name='par' id='par${idx}' tabindex='-1'> 
    <option selected>...</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
  </select>
  </td>

  <td>
  <input type='number' class='text-center form-control index' name='index' id='index${idx}' tabindex='-1'>
  </td>

  <td>
  <input type='number' class='text-center form-control strokes' name='strokes' id='strokes${idx}' tabindex='-1' min='-4'>
  </td>

  <td>
    <select class='custom-select score text-center' id='score${idx}' name='score' tabindex='-1'>
      <option selected>...</option>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='4'>4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
      <option value='6'>6</option>
      <option value='7'>7</option>
      <option value='8'>8</option>
      <option value='9'>9</option>
      <option value='0'>NR</option>
      </select>
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type='number' class='text-center form-control outIn' name='outIn' id='outIn${idx}' tabindex='-1'>
  </td>
  <td>
  <output class='text-center form-control points' name='points' id='points${idx}' tabindex='-1'></output>
  </td>
</tr>`);
  }
}

$('#scoreCard').on('input', ':input', calcScore);

function calcScore(e) {
  var pr, sk, sc, pt = 0,
    tt = 0;
  $('tr').find(':input, output').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('par')) {
      pr = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('strokes')) {
      sk = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('score')) {
      sc = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('points')) {
      pt = (pr + sk) - (sc + 2);
      if (pt < 1 || sc === 0) {
        $(this).val(0);
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.hole').addClass('under').removeClass('over');
      } else if (Number.isNaN(pt)) {
        $(this).val('');
      } else {
        $(this).val(pt);
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.hole').addClass('over').removeClass('under');
        tt += pt;
      }
    }
  });
  if (Number.isNaN(tt)) {
    $('#total').val('');
  } else {
    $('#total').val(tt);
  }
}

addRow('.game', idx, 18);
```

```css
.round {
  width: 96%;
}

select.custom-select {
  width: 8ch;
}

input.index.index,
input.strokes.strokes,
input.outIn.outIn {
  width: 7ch;
}

output.points.points,
output.form-control.hole.hole {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7ch;
}

output.form-control.hole.hole.under::after {
  content: '\a0\1f3cc\a0';
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

output.form-control.hole.hole.over::after {
  content: '\a0\1f6a9\a0';
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

caption.title.title {
  caption-side: top;
  font-size: 1.45rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.5ex;
}

.total-header b {
  vertical-align: sub;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  height: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(9) td {
  border-bottom: 4px ridge rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
}

.form-control.form-control,
.custom-select.custom-select {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<form id='scoreCard'>
  <table class='table table-sm round'>
    <caption class='title'>
      <figure class='figure logo'>&#9971;</figure>
      SO Links</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class='text-center'>Hole</th>
        <th class='text-center'>Par</th>
        <th class='text-center'>Index</th>
        <th class='text-center'>Strokes</th>
        <th class='text-center'>Score</th>
        <th class='text-center'>Out/In</th>
        <th class='text-center'>Points</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class='game'></tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td class='text-right total-header' colspan='6'><b>Total</b> </td>
        <td>
          <output class='text-center form-control total' name='total' id='total' tabindex='-1'></output></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort in your answer, 6 weeks ago I'd never written a line of code so will take your words and use to improve my future coding. Will take some time to digest and understand your answer, but I will get there. You mentioned the hidden column, maybe I was going about things the wrong way, but i need that holeID in the database as a foreign key to reference the 'hole' table where all the details of each courses holes are kept.

Comment: A better area to place details for `<table>` would be a [`<tfoot>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tfoot) placed after the `<tbody>`. If you want to actually show the content but have concerns about its size and how it ungainly it looks in the layout, you could wrap the content into a [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)